# Некорректно работает расширение Автоформатирование в vscode (autopep8, python, vscode)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

У меня установлен Visual Studio Code  Версия: 1.85.1
ОС: Windows_NT x64 10.0.22631
Я установил через pip install autopep8 формартер для python:
C:\Users\akash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Scripts\autopep8.exe
Установил расширение autopep8 в vscode. Выбрал его по умолчанию: "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.autopep8"
Мой файл для тестирования main.py:

```
1  my_list = [1, 2, 3]
2
3  print(my_list)
4
```

Если я намеренно вношу в него лишние пробелы так:

```
1  my_list =    [   1, 2, 3   ]
2  
3  print(   my_list  )
4
```

и форматирую с помощью сочетания клавиш Ctrl+Alt+F то файл возвращается к исходному виду «правильному» виду.

Если я вношу в него пробелы (лишние отступы) так:

```
1  my_list = [1, 2, 3]
2  
3              print(my_list)
4
```

То форматирование в окне редактора с помощью сочетания клавиш Ctrl+Alt+F не работает. В панели состояния ошибки, при запуске в терминале.

Но если я в терминале ввожу команду

```
> autopep8 --in-place --aggressive main.py
```

То файл форматируется и возвращается к правильному виду:
Пробовал устанавливать другие расширения автоформатирования, результат такой же. То есть, как я понимаю, установленный autopep8 C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Scripts\autopep8.exe
работает правильно – исправляет ошибки, в том числе с отступами, а расширение autopep8 – исправляет не все.

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку расширение autopep8 воспринимает этот код (с лишними отступами в начале строки) не python код (не валидный код), то и не форматирует в отличие от системного> autopep8 -i file.py.

Comment: А решение в итоге какое? Не использовать расширение, форматировать из командной строки?

Comment: Пока да. Или из командной строки, или из терминала vscode.